# Losslessly change the dpi value of a JPEG on Linux

Tags: linux, jpeg, dpi

How can I change the `dpi` value recorded in a JPEG file without actually touching anything else, nor recompressing the image?

Linux compatible solutions are welcome.

[This 2011 link](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=618360) says we may not have had a tool to do it back then...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`exiftool`](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to manipulate EXIF data on different file formats.  It's a perl-library accompanied by a command line utility:

```
$ exiftool test.jpg | grep -i resolution
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Focal Plane X Resolution        : 3959.322034
Focal Plane Y Resolution        : 3959.322034
Focal Plane Resolution Unit     : inches
```

In this example, EXIF data tells that `test.jpg` has a resolution of 72×72 dpi.  To update this values to e.g. 100×100, `exiftool` would have to be called like the following:

```
$ exiftool -XResolution=100 -YResolution=100 test.jpg
1 image files updated
```

And voilà:

```
$ exiftool test.jpg | grep -i resolution
X Resolution                    : 100
Y Resolution                    : 100
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Focal Plane X Resolution        : 3959.322034
Focal Plane Y Resolution        : 3959.322034
Focal Plane Resolution Unit     : inches
```

Comment: I also had to add `-ResolutionUnit=inches` because JPEGs produced by Simple Scan didn't even have that.